# Не удается скомпилировать less файл

Tags: cmd, npm, less, git-bash

При попытке скомпилировать файл ./index.less в git-Bash выдается ошибка:

```
lessc ./index.less bundle.css
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:550
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Git\node_modules\less\bin\lessc'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules    /cjs/loader.js:548:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:475:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:695:10)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:516:3)
```

При компиляции через cmd никаких проблем нет. Less установлен глобально и локально, Git — Latest source Release 2.17.0 . Как это исправить?

Comment: а вы webpack используете ?

Comment: Нет, без  Webpack. Установлен Gulp.

Answer (score 1):

Этот и другие баги исчезли после установки более старой версии Git.